# Determine the ratio $k$ so that the sum of the series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} l_{i}$ is equal to the circumference of the outermost circle.

Tags: calculus, geometric-series

**Question:**

Consider an infinite series of concentric circles, were the radii $r_{0}, r_{1}, r_{2}, ...$ form a geometric series with the ratio $k$, $0 < k < 1$.

From a point on the outermost circle, a tangent line is drawn to the circle just inside it, a tangent line from this circle to the one just inside it and so on.

The length of the successive tangents are $l_{0}, l_{1}, l_{2}, ...$
[image: 1]

(the image is a bit grainy, but $r_{0}$ is the radius of the outermost circle)

Determine the ratio $k$ so that the sum of the series

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} l_{i}$$

is equal to the circumference of the outermost circle.

**Attemped answer:**

According to the last part of the question:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} l_{i} = 2 \pi r_{0}$$

Since this is also a geometric series, it can be written as:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} l_{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} l_{0} k^{i} = l_{0} \frac{1}{1-k}$$

since $l_{0}$ is the first term and $k$ is the ratio. Putting these two together gives:

$$l_{0} \frac{1}{1-k} =  2 \pi r_{0}$$

However, this means that I have one equation and three unknowns. I suspect that there is something to be gotten from the fact that the circles are concentric and so this might yield a relationship between $l_{0}$ and $r_{0}$.

For instance, if we form two congruent triangles where $l_{0}$ and $r_{0}$ are two of the sides for the first one, and $l_{1}$ and $r_{1}$ two of the sides for the second one and use Pythagoras theorem, it looks like we get:

$$l_{0} = \sqrt{r_{0}^{2} - r_{1}^{2}}$$

..but this just looks like we get another unknown into the mix instead.

Looks like I am a bit stuck. What are some productive ways to drive this question home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality we may assume that the outer circle has radius $1$.

If $l_0$ is as in the OP, then $l_0^2=1-k^2$. So by scaling we have $l_1=k\sqrt{1-k^2}$, $l_2=k^2\sqrt{1-k^2}$, and so on.

The sum of the geometric series is $\frac{\sqrt{1-k^2}}{1-k}$, that is, $\frac{\sqrt{1+k}}{\sqrt{1-k}}$. Set this equal to $2\pi$ and solve for $k$.

Comment: It should be $l_0^2=1-k^\color{red}{2},l_1=k\sqrt{1-k^{\color{red}{2}}}$ and so on.

Comment: @mathlove: Thank you. Fixed, I think.  Must have been too much Christmas cheer.