# Sum of the tangents of an infinite number of concentric circles should equal the diameter of the first circle

Tags: calculus

First of all this is the same question as: [Determine the ratio $k$ so that the sum of the series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} l_{i}$ is equal to the circumference of the outermost circle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589012/determine-the-ratio-k-so-that-the-sum-of-the-series-sum-i-0-infty-l-i?rq=1)

But I am attempting a different method of solving it.

**Question:**

So imagine that we have an infinite number of concentric circles with the radiuses:

$$r_0, r_1, r_2, ...$$

Where the radiuses is a geometric series with the ratio $k$, $0 < k < 1$. From a point on the outer circle a tangent is drawn to the next closest circle and so on. The length of the tangents can be written as $l_0, l_1, l_2, ... $.

Define the ratio $k$ So that the sum of the series:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} l_i$$

Is equal to the outer circle circumference. Like this:

[image]

**My attempt at a solution:**

The sum of the geometric series should be $$S_n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} l_i = 2 r \pi $$

Since the circles gets smaller with the factor $k$, this could be viewed as a uniform scaling and rotation of the top circle (and tangent) we arrive at the following equality:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} l_i = l_i \frac{1 - k^n}{1 - k} = l_i \frac{1}{1 - k} = 2 r \pi $$

Without loss of generality we can set the radius to one:

$$l_i \frac{1}{1 - k} = 2 \pi $$

Looking at this picture we can see that: $l_0 = k, l_1 = k^2, ... Etc$

[image]

This means that we can write:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} l_i = k \frac{1 - k^n}{1 - k} = k \frac{1}{1 - k} = 2 \pi $$

This gives us:

$$\frac{k}{1 - k} = 2 \pi \implies k = \frac{2\pi}{2\pi + 1}$$

But this is appearantly wrong. My textbook says the answer should be:

$$k = \frac{4\pi^2 -1}{4\pi^2 + 1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the first circle have radius $a$ and $r < 1$ be the ratio. Let the circles be $C_0, C_1, \dots,$.

Let's calculate $l_n$, the distance between circle $C_n$ and $C_{n+1}$.

We first draw the segment $l_n$ that is tangent to $C_{n+1}$ and intersects $C_n$. This forms a right angle, so by pythagorean theorem we have

$$l_n^2 = (ar^n)^2 - (ar^{n+1})^2$$

Hence, $l_n = \sqrt{1 - r^2} ar^n$.

Now, we solve the series:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} l_n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sqrt{1-r^2} ar^n &= 2 \pi a \\
\frac{\sqrt{1 - r^2}}{1 - r} = \sqrt{\frac{1-r}{1+r}}&= 2 \pi \\
\frac{1-r}{1+r} &= 4 \pi ^2 \\
r &= \frac{4 \pi^2 - 1}{4 \pi^2 + 1}
\end{align}

as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Soke. Is it possible for you and look were my calculation was wrong? That would be much appreciated.

Comment: @LukasArvidsson I think you calculated the initial $l_0$ wrong. In that right triangle you drew, the hypotenuse is $1$, but the leg other than $l_0$ should be $k$ (since this is the radius of the inner circle). Thus, $l_0 = \sqrt{1 - k^2}$, rather than the $k$ you supposed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but aren't both of the legs k, I.e. Both have the same length as the radius of the inner circle?? Both have the same size on the leftover part from the first circle to the second?

Comment: I have updated the figure to clarify this.

Comment: So i guess that the questions I have is if $l_0, l_1, l_2 ..., l_n$ is equal to $k, k^2, k^3, ..., k^n$ and if not, why? What do you think @Soke

Comment: @LukasArvidsson Your diagram is misleading because of the value of $k$ you chose it seems as though they are equal, however this is not true in general. Try drawing a diagram where $k$ is very small, like $1/10$ (so the inner circle will be 10 times smaller). You'll find that $l_0$ is much different from $k$ in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!